# How uploadify upload function response should look like

Tags: php, symfony, response, uploadify

This is my uploadify onUploadSuccess handle:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file,data,response) {
        ...
 },
```

I need to pass some data to this function from upload function, like for example new updated file name. How should my response in upload function look like? I want pass data.newName field and get it like this:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file,data,response) {
        alert(data.newName);
 },
```

I'm using symfony2 on php side.

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Comment: We can take for example default uploadify script: http://pastebin.com/cy9THDjg